# Why does the following sentence use "have finished" even though the tense is present?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, present-tense

I have a very puzzling question about English grammar.

> I am thinking of taking a vacation when I have finished all the job.

The tense of the sentence is as present. In addition, the author even mentions something that would happen in the future.
However, "having finished" is being used.

I thought it should be...

> I am thinking of taking a vacation when I will have finished all the job.

Would you please give me a grammatical explanation about this?

Comment: I wonder if this answer would help: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56936/3306 .

Comment: "finished the job" would be better by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The future is never used after "when". Here is a full explanation that includes as well other words for which you shouldn't use the future: [Jakub Marian](https://jakubmarian.com/will-after-when-in-english/).

There are exceptions to this rule and they are explained also in the reference given above.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: I am studying the content of the link you gave me.
Seems like sooooo helpful! :D